# How do I reuse a component with few additional functionalities in angular

Tags: angular, devexpress

I am working on an Angular Project which has user stats component basically which uses widgets of the Devexpress package and has a service plugged in to get the data from the server. And I have to create another page with the kinda the same view but few extra widgets and functionalities to be added to it. The question I m facing is should I use the concept of inheritance in the Angular project because there are few issues related to the properties and methods in the first component as they are private and need to be used in the new component I m creating. Also, I found few Q&A and blogs which suggest against using the concept of inheritance in Angular which sounds a bit strange for person who has worked mostly with python and Java. Any particular Angular concepts I should use here like ng-content or something.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I highly recommend using nested components. By creating the shared and common functionality in one component or “widget”, using it and adding to it in the parent component. Inheritance is still available in angular but I don’t believe it is the best way.

Comment: Could you help me out here. The issue I have is I m using a widget datagrid which has on toolbarloading which is a function triggered so as to load a group by and refresh button. But since I don't need them in the home page but I need them in the second page how should I move forward. Just started with angular so don't have much idea.

Comment: You can separate the toolbarloading and refresh button from your widget to another component by their on. Then, you can have a core component that has the datagrid only, and another one which has the datagrid plus the toolbarloading and refresh button

Comment: But actually the toolbar is inside the data grid selector. I have attached a link to a sample which would give u a better idea : https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/ToolbarCustomization/Angular/Light/

Comment: Here actually on my front page I just want the refresh button functionality but for the summary page, I need group by and such other functionalities.